# merge a 2D numpy array with another 2D based on indices from a third 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array, 'construct' (17 rows, 1531900 columns). I have created a second numpy array of zeros, 'new_var' (17 rows, 8928000 columns). I would like to insert my 'construct' array into my 'new_var' array with each row going into its respective rows and each column value from construct going into new_var based on the indices given by a third array idx_arr (1 row, 1531900 columns).

I.e:

```
new_var:
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])

idx_arr:
array([[1695453, 1695608, 1695763, ..., 7200121, 7200276, 7201360]])

construct[0, :]:
array([-0.63766944, -0.653992  , -0.5967345 , ..., -0.7344175 ,
       -0.7344163 , -0.7344165 ], dtype=float32)

construct[1, :]
array([0.05108674,  0.01683133,  0.07986307, ..., -0.9598859 ,
       -0.959886  , -0.9598871 ], dtype=float32)
```

For example, the elements in construct[0,0] (-0.63766944) and construct[0,1] (-0.653992) would go into new_var at indices 0, 1695453 and 0, 1695608 respectively. Elements in construct[1, 0] and construct[1, 1] would go into new_var at indices 1, 1695453 and 1, 1695608 respectively.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [MRE]? With an emphasis on minimal.

Comment: Make a 2x5 target array, try sticking a 2x3 array with a 1x3 index into it. Show your attempt. That's how you make a [mcve]. Hopefully you can figure out how to generalize that by copy-and-pasting directly into your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.